# Styling sherlock ActionMode background

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Can't seem to style the ActionMode background.

I've already overridden actionbar background but setting the ActionMode background doesn't seem to work:

```
<style name="Theme.apptheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">

...

<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>

<item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/actionmode_background</item>
<item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/actionmode_split</item>

...

</style>
```

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: On which API level have you tried? Have you tried also android:actionModeBackground ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're likely testing on ICS or JB, and therefore will not see any difference. You must **also** include these tags using the `android:` namespace.

E.g.

```
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>

<item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/actionmode_background</item>
<item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/actionmode_split</item>
```

Comment: Of course, why didn't I think of that!? :-) Thank you very much!