# How to change ActionMode background color in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-actionmode, actionmode

i am creating an android app in which support level api is 7 so i am using sherlock actionbar. I am using action mode in it.
Issue is i want to change the background of action mode. So i have tried

```
    <item name="android:background">@color/something</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@color/something</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@color/something</item>
```

these style solution's available but none of them works. 
[image]

Comment: that is a contextual action bar

Comment: well @Raghunandan i am not using CAB i am creating custom action mode

Answer (score 18, accepted):

if you want change the color of ActionBar just do this:

```
 ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
 bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("COLOR"));
```

see the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us) for more info

and if you using ActionMode This is the style used for any ActionMode. You'll need to create your own style to customize it

```
<style name="Widget.ActionMode">
<item name="android:background">?android:attr/actionModeBackground</item>
<item name="android:backgroundSplit">?android:attr/actionModeSplitBackground</item>
<item name="android:height">?android:attr/actionBarSize</item>
<item name="android:titleTextStyle">@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.ActionMode.Title</item>
<item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle</item>
</style>
```

more info in [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556116/how-can-i-customize-the-action-modes-color-and-text)

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711612/styling-sherlock-actionmode-background) too

**Edit**

for  pre-Honeycomb see [this](https://www.miximum.fr/blog/porting-the-contextual-anction-mode-for-pre-honeycomb-android-apps/) please

maybe [this](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/creating-contextual-action-mode-for-single-views-in-pre-honeycomb-versions-using-sherlock-library/) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531272/state-activated-on-pre-honeycomb-devices) helped you

Comment: thanks for your response now its working fine above api 11 but i need to give support for api 7 also

Comment: Pre-honeycomb link is 404

Comment: @TimCooke I've edit my post with new link, thanks to mention,

Comment: `titleTextStyle` and `subtitleTextStyle` are not public.

Answer (score 35):

In my case i resolved with this. First i created a style to define the actionModeBackground:

```
<style name="MyTheme.ActionMode" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

Then i add the style into my base application theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:actionModeStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionMode</item>
</style>
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: For supporting pre and post-lollipop devices, you need to add also: <item name="actionModeBackground">@color/bg_action_bar</item>

Comment: You can also just set actionModeBackground directly on the Theme as well. Need both the prefixed and unprefixed versions to support 4.x and 5.x respectively.

Comment: this <item name="android:actionModeBackground">#FFFFFF</item> doesn't work for me. this  <item name="actionModeBackground">@color/bg_action_bar</item> does! Thanks Kokusho

Comment: Pre-lollipop: also add `actionModeStyle` (without `android:` prefix). If using appcompat Toolbar, you need to style `background` directly; see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28374774

Answer (score 16):

If you are using simple [Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html) then try this,

```
ActionBar abar = getActionBar();
abar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xff123456));
```

But if you are using [Actionbar share lock Lib](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) then try this

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xff123456));
```

`ColorDrawable(0xff123456)` - should be your color code.

**Drawable/styles.xml**

```
 <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
 <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
```

**Change Theme as per API level**

If you want to change as per the API level then you should go for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15339150/androidactionbarstyle-requires-api-level-11)

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556116/how-can-i-customize-the-action-modes-color-and-text)& [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711612/styling-sherlock-actionmode-background)

Comment: hi @chntan i tried this but all of them working for api above 11 nothing for api 7 please help me if you have something for api 7

Comment: As i have mention you in answer that , you should use  [Actionbarshare lock Lib](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) for below 11 API. because ActionBar is not for 11 and higher.

Comment: yes i am using actionbarsherlock but i have to change background of action mode in api 7. Now its changing in api 11 and above

Comment: Okay, got it, mean you want to change in only 7, for 11 it should be different ? is it like this ?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do it programmatically (supporting AppCompat) you need to look for icon parent view. This code is tested from 2.3.7 to 6.0.1. You need to check on lower API... .

**first get your activity decor view**

```
final ViewGroup  decorView = (ViewGroup) getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
```

**second set the color in onPrepareActionMode. You can also set the back icon  or other elements here**

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) 
{

     decorView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

     @Override
     public void run() 
     {
        int buttonId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_mode_close_button", "id", "android");

        View v = decorView.findViewById(buttonId);
        if (v == null)
        {
           buttonId = R.id.action_mode_close_button;
            v = decorView.findViewById(buttonId);   
        }

        if (v != null)
        {                         
           ((View)v.getParent()).setBackgroundColor(Color.red /*your color here*/);
        }               
     }   
     }, 500);}
```

Answer (score 2):

Override this style in your custom theme:

```
<style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode" parent="">
    <item name="background">?attr/actionModeBackground</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">?attr/actionModeSplitBackground</item>
    <item name="height">?attr/actionBarSize</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionMode.Title</item>
    <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle</item>
    <item name="closeItemLayout">@layout/abc_action_mode_close_item_material</item>
</style>
```

For example:

```
<style name="LywActionMode" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
    <item name="background">@color/lyw_primary_color</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@color/lyw_primary_color</item>
</style>

<style name="LywCompatTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    ...
    <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/LywActionMode</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the style used for any ActionMode, I pulled it from the SDK. You'll need to create your own style to customize it. It's really easy to do. If you've never done anything like this before, you should read through [this post](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html) on customizing the ActionBar. It explains everything you'll need to know.

```
<style name="Widget.ActionMode">
<item name="android:background">?android:attr/actionModeBackground</item>
<item name="android:backgroundSplit">?android:attr/actionModeSplitBackground</item>
<item name="android:height">?android:attr/actionBarSize</item>
<item name="android:titleTextStyle">@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.ActionMode.Title</item>
<item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle</item>
</style>
```

Comment: "Cannot resolve symbol Widget" lol. And what is min API of this?

Answer (score 1):

For those who still struggle, and none of the existing solutions helps, please make sure that in your layout with toolbar you have this:

```
app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.ToolBar"
android:popupTheme="@style/Theme.ToolBar"
```

and you don't have

```
app:theme="@style/Theme.ToolBar"
```

Since they will rise a conflict and your customization will not work.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do it

```
ActionBarContextView actionBar = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(R.id.action_mode_bar);
    actionBar.setBackgroundColor(WhateverColorYouWant);
```

Answer (score -1):

I wanna make more clearer this answer. First create custom background "storage_list_header_shape.xml" in your drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shape="rectangle" >

   <gradient
      android:angle="270"
      android:startColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
      android:centerColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
      android:endColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />

   <size android:height="3dp" />

 </shape>
```

Second, create custom style in your style.xml

```
<style name="customActionModeTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/storage_list_header_shape</item>
</style>
```

Third, call the style in your manifest.

```
<activity
     android:name="com.javacafe.activities.Main"
     android:launchMode="singleTop"
     android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
     android:theme="@style/customActionModeTheme" >
</activity>
```