# ActionMode background doesn't work with set support ActionBar with Toolbar

Tags: android, background, toolbar, actionmode

My action mode background in style doesn't work since i use ToolBar to be ActionBar.

part of MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    startActionMode(new ActionMode.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {

        }
    });
}
```

layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.dowob.testactionmodestyle.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            android:id="@+id/textView"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

part of manifest

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/MainActivityTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

styles.xml

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MainActivityTheme" parent="AppTheme">

        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>

        <item name="colorPrimary">#FF0000</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#FF00FF</item>

        <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/ActionMode</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeStyle">@style/ActionMode</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionMode" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
        <item name="android:background">@color/actionModeBg</item>
        <item name="background">@color/actionModeBg</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

I've tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28412766/4557420) but still not work.

[This is my whole project](https://github.com/aiueoH/TestActionMode).

Does anyone know how to solve it?? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solve this problem by my coworker, just remove the theme of AppBarLayout them it work fine.

Before:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

After :

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was in Toolbar theme.
It's weird, but the style for ActionMode doesn't work if Toolbar theme is Theme.AppCompat.(any), not ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.(any).

Maybe it will help someone.