# How to customize actionbar of setMultichoicie listview

Tags: java, android, listview

Here is my **style.xml** code:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

when I put a setChoice on my `listView`, the action bar changes color and becomes black, I would like it to keep the same color (colorPrimary), where to change that?

Comment: upp upp upp upp upp

Comment: You may find this thread useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28374774/unable-to-style-action-mode-when-using-toolbar