# How to change Action Mode's color and text

Tags: android, android-actionmode

I want to Change Action mode  background  and title color in it . i tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769315/how-to-change-actionmode-background-color-in-android) But nothing has changed

Here is my styles.xml file

```
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light"></style>


    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme"></style>

    <style name="LiveoActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/LiveoActionBar</item>                
    </style>

    <style name="LiveoActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/Liveo.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/Liveo.SubTitleTextStyle</item>               
        <item name="background">@color/green_google_play</item>                
    </style>

    <style name="Liveo.TitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    </style>    

    <style name="Liveo.SubTitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    </style>   

    <style name="menu_labels_style">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/fab_label_background</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

Comment: did you make sure to reference these styles in your manifest?

Comment: @ Tomer Shemesh yes  sir it is reference in   <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/LiveoActionBarTheme" >

Answer (score 0):

Update your code as follows and try ,

```
<style name="LiveoActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/LiveoActionBar</item>                
</style>

<style name="LiveoActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Liveo.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/Liveo.SubTitleTextStyle</item>               
    <item name="android:background">@color/green_google_play</item>                
</style>
```

Comment: What is the difference !!