# How to change the background color of a TextView inside of an ActionMode

Tags: android, android-actionbar, styles, android-actionmode

I have a `TextView` inside of my action bar, like the following:

[image: non-action mode image]

I have logic configured to make it overlay the `Toolbar` with an `ActionMode` when I long-press on an item in the associated `ListView`. This ends up looking like the following:

[image: action mode image]

This is basically correct, except for the annoying background around the `TextView` title in the `ActionMode`.

I've tried quite a few things, from changing the `Widget.ActionMode` style in my `styles.xml` file, to actually setting the `actionModeStyle` to a specific style. Nothing seems to affect this `TextView`, though.

I have read through [How to change ActionMode background color in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769315/how-to-change-actionmode-background-color-in-android) but it doesn't seem like anything I do has an effect on this background.

**Side Note**: It would be really nice if there were some way to view the style hierarchy on an Android device as it's rendered. The hierarchy viewer gets me about 1/3 of the way there, but it doesn't have any style information. Anyone know of such a tool that I could use to debug this problem?

**styles.xml (only relevant stuff):**

```
<style name="Material" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="textHeaderMaxLines">@integer/text_header_max_lines</item>
    <item name="trackAbstractMaxLines">@integer/track_abstract_max_lines</item>
    <item name="activatableItemBackground">@drawable/activatable_item_background</item>

    <!-- ActionMode Styles -->
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@color/app_green_dark</item>
</style>
<style name="Material.AppBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/app_green</item>
    <item name="android:color">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
<style name="Material.AppBar.ActionMode" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionMode.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/app_green_dark</item>
</style>
```

Comment: i am not sure if i understand you problem , if you need to change the background according to your  editText State you can do that with [state](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) in your editText background

Comment: @MuhannadFakhouri It's not an `EditText`, it's the default `TextView` that's a title within the `ActionMode`. I set the text itself with `setTitle()` on the `ActionMode` object. I would like to know how to set the style, since the current solutions I gleaned from the other SO posts don't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try to use the hack way to change the backgroud:

**Via Java:**

1. Use `hierarchyviewer.bat` to analyse the layout, focus on the `ActionMode` view, you can see below: (Title ID: `action_bar_title`, SubTitle ID:`action_bar_subtitle`)

[image]

2.Find the specify `TextView` by the ID we found above, and just do whatever you want!

```
/**
 * To hack the title and subTitle in ActionMode
 */
private void hack() {
    int titleID = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
    View titleView = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(titleID);
    if ((titleView != null) && (titleView instanceof TextView)) {
        ((TextView) titleView).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
    int subTitleID = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_subtitle", "id", "android");
    View subTitleView = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(subTitleID);
    if ((subTitleView != null) && (subTitleView instanceof TextView)) {
        ((TextView) subTitleView).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
}
```

3.You can call this method when `ActionMode` create, for example: in `onCreateActionMode()`. Final result：

[image]

**Via Style:**

Or you can try to set a `android:actionModeStyle` to control the title and subTitle background, but the `android:background` seems not work for it:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeStyle">@style/TestActionModeStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="TestActionModeStyle">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TestTitleStyle</item>
    <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/TestSubTitleStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="TestTitleStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
</style>

<style name="TestSubTitleStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item>
</style>
```

**Edit:**

**By the way:**

I think the most flexible way is custom you own `ActionMode` view, this can be easy to achieve, just set a custom view:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode pMode, Menu pMenu) {
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
    findView(...);
    initView(...);
    pMode.setCustomView(layout);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Bill. I'll check this out as soon as I have a chance.

Comment: I ended up creating a custom view, as recommended. Thanks for the answer, @Bill.

Comment: @jwir3 Yes, I use the same way in my project!