# How to change color in ActionBar when I start ActionMode

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-styles

When I start `ActionMode` (I make this when I set items in `ListView`) my ToolBar change background color from dark to white and I got this:

[image]

How you can see - it's looked bad.

How I can change `ToolBar` background color when `ActionMode` is activated?

Comment: visit this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769315/how-to-change-actionmode-background-color-in-android.

Comment: @AmitVaghela answer it and I close this answer

Answer (score 1):

Change the ActionMode background with use of actionModeStyle attribute

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
....
....
<item name="actionModeStyle">@style/LStyled.ActionMode</item>
</style>

<style name="LStyled.ActionMode" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
<item name="background">@color/color_action_mode_bg</item>
</style>
```

You need to define a color named color_action_mode_bg:

```
<color name="color_action_mode_bg">#009688</color>
```

There are other things you can change as well. e.g:

```
<item name="titleTextStyle">...</item>
<item name="subtitleTextStyle">...</item>
<item name="height">...</item>
```

To change text color of text Citroen add the following to AppTheme.Base:

```
<item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/color_action_mode_text</item>
```

Updated Code

```
<style name="Widget.ActionMode">
<item name="android:background">?android:attr/actionModeBackground</item>
<item name="android:backgroundSplit">?android:attr/actionModeSplitBackground</item>
<item name="android:height">?android:attr/actionBarSize</item>
<item name="android:titleTextStyle">@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.ActionMode.Title</item>
<item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle</item>
</style>
```

Comment: and if you using ActionMode This is the style used for any ActionMode. You'll need to create your own style to customize it so try my updated code

Comment: http://dl1.joxi.net/drive/0004/0191/303295/151221/7f4e93d1d2.jpg - I must extend this?