# Android toolbar action mode background color not set correctly

Tags: android, toolbar

The following is my app theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    ...

    <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/AppStyle.ActionMode</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeStyle">@style/AppStyle.ActionMode</item>

</style>

<style name="AppStyle.ActionMode" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">

    <item name="background">@color/color_action_mode_background</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@color/color_action_mode_background</item>

</style>
```

It does not work. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change ActionMode background color in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769315/how-to-change-actionmode-background-color-in-android)

Comment: I have seen the answer but the solution is not working for me. Infact none of the available solutions is working. What am i doing wrong ?