# actionModeBackground is not working in lower Version?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

This code is working fine in lollipop and above lollipop version but not working in lower Version so any Solution for this.

```
<style name="DocumentsTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

    <item name="background">@color/brownish_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/lightblack</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/brownish_dark</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/lightblack</item>




</style>
```

Comment: Might helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20769315/7734566

Comment: thanks i tried this but getting same result