# Change ActionMode background color in Material3

Tags: android, material-design, android-styles, android-actionmode, material3

Starting from Material3 I can not change the action mode background color.

Before Material3, I managed to change the background color with `actionModeBackground` attribute:

```
<item name="actionModeBackground">@color/some_color</item>
```

Here is my theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">false</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@color/action_mode_background</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/ic_baseline_done_tick_24</item>
</style>
```

I also checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769315/how-to-change-actionmode-background-color-in-android) thread but doesn't seem to work for material3.

How can I change the action mode background color with Material3?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`actionModeStyle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#actionModeStyle) style attribute to set a custom style to the Action Mode, and then change the action mode background with `background` attribute:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/action_mode_style</item>    

</style>

<style name="action_mode_style" parent="@style/Widget.Material3.ActionMode">
    <item name="background">@color/action_mode_background</item>
</style>
```